# How to invoke same Lambda function from two different AWS Services (SQS and SNS)?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

The following code invoke SNS but I want SQS to invoke it as well. Can we use multiple Principal and Source Arn? I have also tried this but did not work -

```
LambdaPermissionMainSNS:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunctionMain.Arn
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Ref SNSTopic
LambdaPermissionMainSQS:
   Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
   Properties:
     Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
     FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunctionMain.Arn
     Principal: sqs.amazonaws.com
     SourceArn: !Ref SQSQueue
```

Comment: Probably not. You could configure it manually via the Lambda Management Console. Do you need it to be automated?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein -  yes , it need to be automated. I edited my comment with option I have tried  but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an [`AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html) resource for SQS:

```yml
SQSEventSource:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
  Properties: 
    BatchSize: 10 # this is the default
    Enabled: true
    EventSourceArn: !Ref SQSQueue
    FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunctionMain.Arn
```

> The AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping resource creates a mapping between an event source and an AWS Lambda function. Lambda reads items from the event source and triggers the function.

You can then have both SNS and SQS "trigger" your Lambda function. You will have to implement your own logic inside the function to deal with the different event formats.

See also [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).